# Add a safe sender using the Gmail API?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, spam-prevention

Is it possible to add an address or domain to the safe senders list using the Gmail API? Not for malicious reasons, of course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gmail does not have a "safe sender list", per se.

BUT, two ways that you can achieve some of the same effect are:  (a) adding the email address to contacts, and/or (b) adding a filter for that email address (or domain) that makes the message always go to the inbox.

For adding contacts via an API, see the `people.createContact` method on the people API:  https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/createContact

For adding filters via an API, see "managing filters" for the Gmail API:  https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filter_settings